# restore Jailbroken iPod touch 4g by ipsw file

Tags: itunes, restore, ipod, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I've read almost 20 articles about restoring iPod touch 4g but none of them actually helped me. I know DFU mode and i know shift + restore and selecting ipsw file path. But while itunes extracts the imported file, suddenly crashes.
Is there any working method to restore iPod touch 4g ?

iTunes version: `11.1.1.5`
iOS version: `6.1`
PC OS: `Windows 8`

Comment: Have you tried installing an older version of iTunes? If yours is up to date and the tutorials are slightly dated, they could've patched it such that IPSW files are checked in some manner... I wish I could help more, this is simply the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to work for apple, and this sort of issue is pretty common when restoring.   You might have the most current version of iTunes installed, but what you need to do is completely remove iTunes and all of the components that get installed with it.

**1.. Remove iTunes and its related components from the Control Panel**

Use the Control Panel to uninstall iTunes and related software components in the following order and restart your computer:

- iTunes
- Apple Software Update
- Apple Mobile Device Support
- Bonjour
- Apple Application Support (iTunes 9 or later)

**Important**: Uninstalling these components in a different order or only uninstalling some of these components may have unintended effects.

**Important**: You have to restart your computer after removing each of the items listed above.

**2..   Make sure that iTunes and its related components are completely uninstalled**

Removing iTunes and its related components from the Control Panel should remove all its supporting files. After following the previous steps, you should confirm that the following files and folders have been removed. If any are left behind, remove them now:

> C:\Program Files\Bonjour\
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\
>
> C:\Program Files\iTunes\
>
> C:\Program Files\iPod\

**3.. Reinstall iTunes and its related components**

After you make sure that iTunes is completely uninstalled, restart your computer and install the latest version of iTunes.

If the issue you're troubleshooting isn't resolved after following these steps, it isn't necessary to remove and reinstall iTunes multiple times. Instead, you may find helpful information at the iTunes Support page, such as troubleshooting steps related to specific alert messages.

**iPodService.exe Alert**

Follow these steps if the message "Cannot delete iPodService.exe: It is being used by another person or program" appears when you try to delete the iPod folder.

1. Make sure that iTunes and the iPod Updater utility aren't open.
2. Press and hold Control-Alt-Delete.
3. Select Start Task Manager.
4. Click the Processes tab.
5. Locate iPodService.exe in the list.
6. Click iPodService.exe and choose End Process.
7. Quit the Task Manager.

If that does not work, I would suggest finding a friend that will allow you to install iTunes on their computer.  That should work equally as well.

Comment: With many thanks for your help. It worked. But, now I'm facing with a new problem. Do you have any suggestion to solve it? Checkout the edit please.

Comment: And also I should mention again that my iPod is jailbroken. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I will help you, but if this answer was correct could you copy paste your edit into a new question since it is essentially a new question.

Comment: WOW that is a strange apple KB article.   It actually tells people to edit the hosts file!??!   Did you follow the KB article?  Where are you trying to do the restore from?  Home?  School?   That error is the result of not being able to connect to the iTunes update server.   Do you run any 3rd party anti-virus or firewall software?   Is the internet connection you use restricted in any way (are certain sites blocked?)

Comment: I have quite a few suggestions, but the nature of this issue does warrant you opening another question.

Comment: Here is another question: [Error 3491 while restoring jailbroken iPod touch 4g](http://superuser.com/questions/745767/error-3491-while-restoring-jailbroken-ipod-touch-4g)